# Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV).Pycharm error in Mac Apple silicon .Not using opencv till now in this project

Tags: python-3.x, pip, apple-m1

```
import sys

import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
# import pyaudio
import os
import webbrowser
from keyboard import press_and_release
# from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import pywhatkit as kt
import osascript
# from wappdriver import Whatsapp

# from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# import time


engine = pyttsx3.init()
# voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# print(voices)
# engine.setProperty('voice',voices[16].id)
engine.setProperty("rate", 180)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishme():
    h = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if h >= 0 and h < 12:
        speak("Good Morning ! ")
    elif h >= 12 and h < 18:
        speak("Good Afternoon ! ")
    else:
        speak("Good Evening ")

    speak("I am jarvis your assistant! How may I help you?")


def takecommand():
    # takes microphone input and return string as output
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    # with sr.Microphone() as source:
    #     r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    #     r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.2)
    #     print("Listening...")
    #     r.pause_threshold = 1
    #     audio = r.listen(source)
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=0) as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=1 , phrase_time_limit=4)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"You said: {query}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Say that again please...")
        return "none"

    return query

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('-------Code Running------')
    speak("Hello Siddhant Sir!")
    # wishme()
    x=2
    while x > 1:
        listen = takecommand().lower()

        if 'wake up jarvis' in listen or 'hello jarvis'in listen:
            speak('Hello and Ready sir')

            while 1:
                if 1:
                    query = takecommand().lower()
                    if 'open whatsapp'in query:
                        speak('Opening whatsapp sir')
                        os.system("open /Applications/WhatsApp.app")

                    elif 'open vs code' in query:
                        speak('Opening visual studio code sir ')
                        os.system("open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app")

                    elif 'open Pycharm' in query:
                        speak('Opening Pycharm  sir ')
                        os.system("open /Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app")

                    elif 'open chrome' in query:
                        speak('Opening chorme sir')
                        os.system("open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app")

                    elif 'open youtube' in query:
                        speak('Sure sir! Opening sir')
                        webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/')

                    elif 'open new tab' in query:
                        webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.google.co.in/')

                    elif 'open discord' in query:
                        speak('opening Discord sir')
                        os.system("open /Applications/Discord.app")

                    elif 'give me something to write my notes on' in query:
                        speak('Opening word sir')
                        os.system("open /Applications/Microsoft\ Word.app")

                    elif 'it is my class time' in query:
                        speak('Opening M S Teams sir')
                        os.system("open /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app")

                    elif 'open my facebook account' in query:
                        speak('Sure sir')
                        webbrowser.open("https://www.facebook.com/")

                    elif 'want to see my professional account' in query:
                        speak('opening sir')
                        webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.linkedin.com/feed/")

                    elif ' open new tab ' in query:
                        press_and_release('command +t')

                    # elif 'open settings' in query:
                    #     speak('opening sir')
                    #     # os.system("open /Applications/System\ Preferences.app")
                    #     os.system("open /Applications/System\ Preferences.app")

                    # elif 'spotlight search' in query:
                    #     speak('sure sir')
                    #     keyboard=Controller()
                    #     key="command"+" "
                    #     keyboard.press(key)
                    #     keyboard.release(key)

                    elif 'volume mute' in query:
                        speak('Muting the volume sir ')
                        target_volume = 0
                        vol = "set volume output volume " + str(0)
                        osascript.osascript(vol)

                    elif 'volume 10' in query:
                        target_volume = 10
                        vol = "set volume output volume " + str(10)
                        osascript.osascript(vol)
                        speak('volume 10 ')

                    elif 'volume 25' in query:
                        target_volume = 25
                        vol = "set volume output volume " + str(25)
                        osascript.osascript(vol)
                        speak('volume 25')

                    elif 'volume 50' in query:
                        target_volume = 50
                        vol = "set volume output volume " + str(50)
                        osascript.osascript(vol)
                        speak('volume 50')

                    elif 'volume 75' in query:
                        target_volume = 75
                        vol = "set volume output volume " + str(75)
                        speak('volume now is 75 sir!')
                        osascript.osascript(vol)
                        speak('volume 75')

                    elif 'volume 90' in query:
                        target_volume = 90
                        vol = "set volume output volume " + str(90)
                        osascript.osascript(vol)
                        speak('volume now is 90 sir!')

                    elif 'volume full' in query:
                        speak('not gonna do that sir')
                        target_volume = 100
                        vol = "set volume output volume " + str(100)
                        speak('volume now is 100 sir!')
                        osascript.osascript(vol)

                    elif 'want to search something on google' in query:
                        speak('what do you want to search sir?')
                        ques = takecommand().lower()
                        kt.search(ques)

                    elif 'play song from youtube' in query:
                        speak('which song you want me to play sir?')
                        ques=takecommand().lower()
                        kt.playonyt(f"{ques}")
                        if 'then sleep' in query:
                            speak('Going to sleep mode sir')
                            break

                    elif 'send message on whatsapp' in query:
                        speak('whom do you want to message sir ?')
                        recipent = takecommand().lower()
                        speak('what is the message sir?')
                        message = takecommand().lower()
                        # with Whatsapp() as bot:
                        #     bot.send(f"{recipent}", f"{message}")

                    elif 'sleep ' in query :
                        speak('Good bye sir')
                        break

                    else:
                        speak('did not get that sir ')

        elif 'Plug off' in listen:
            x=0
            sys.exit()
```

Running the same code after some time and giving me this output or maybe i have done something.Previously it was running all fine.Was trying to code a virtual assistant and opened the code after a day and after running the program it gives me this error. And i would want to know why is this problem coming.

Answer (score 0):

**Background:**
SIGSEGV means segmentation fault, which occurs when a process tries to access an inaccessible memory location.

**Problem**:
In your code, I believe it happens when you're instantiating `pyttsx3`

The problem with this specific scenario is, it happens in the underlying C++ code but these are not C++ exceptions so you can't build exception handlers around signals.
To be precise, segmentation error could occur when the `NSObject` is inherited.
I assume you're using the latest version of [`pyttsx3` module](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/)

**Workaround**
Import the `nsss` drivers before you instantiate `pyttsx3`

Basically,

```py
import importlib

importlib.import_module('pyttsx3.drivers.nsss')
engine = pyttsx3.init()
```

If this doesn't solve the segmentation fault, then there might be a buggy code somewhere (potentially in the modules you use or even in some other language) causing a memory access violation.

If it does solve the problem, you might still receive an `AttributeError` when the [`NSObject` is inherited](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/blob/master/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py#L15)

In that case, go ahead and run

`pip uninstall --no-cache-dir pyttsx3`

and

`pip install --no-cache py3-tts==3.5`

Finally test it,

```py
import pyttsx3
import importlib
from pyttsx3.voice import Voice
from typing import List

importlib.import_module('pyttsx3.drivers.nsss')
driver = pyttsx3.init()
voices: List[Voice] = driver.getProperty("voices")
speaker_voice = "Daniel"
for voice in voices:
    if voice.name == speaker_voice or speaker_voice in voice.name:
        driver.setProperty("voice", voice.id)
        driver.setProperty("rate", 200)
        driver.setProperty("volume", 100)
driver.say(text='hello, how are you')
driver.runAndWait()
```

Hope this helps